# Typescript runtime error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: typescript

I have a React project with Typescript (v. `3.6.3`),

When I build- `npm run build` I'm getting a typescript runtime error:

> ERROR in [internal] INTERNAL ERROR: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined
>       at unescapeLeadingUnderscores

I found out that what's causing the issue is something with `LogRocket` reporter, this is the typescipt object that triggers the error by `console.log` on `typescrit.js`:

```
{
  identifier: NodeObject {
    pos: -1,
    end: -1,
    flags: 8,
    modifierFlagsCache: 0,
    transformFlags: 0,
    parent: undefined,
    kind: 149,
    left: IdentifierObject {
      pos: -1,
      end: -1,
      flags: 8,
      modifierFlagsCache: 0,
      transformFlags: 0,
      parent: undefined,
      escapedText: 'LR',
      originalKeywordKind: undefined,
      autoGenerateFlags: 0,
      autoGenerateId: 0,
      emitNode: [Object],
      symbol: [SymbolObject]
    },
    right: IdentifierObject {
      pos: -1,
      end: -1,
      flags: 8,
      modifierFlagsCache: 0,
      transformFlags: 0,
      parent: undefined,
      escapedText: 'LogRocket',
      originalKeywordKind: undefined,
      autoGenerateFlags: 0,
      autoGenerateId: 0,
      emitNode: [Object],
      symbol: [SymbolObject]
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

`tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Allow importing like `import React from 'react'`
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esNext",

    // Resolve modules using Node-resolution algorithm
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    // Set React as the JSX factory
    "jsx": "react",

    // Include typings from built-in lib declarations
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom", "dom.iterable", "webworker"],

    // Include module source maps for debugging
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "ES2020"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

stack trace:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at unescapeLeadingUnderscores (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13569:19)
>       at Object.idText (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13573:16)
>       at typeToTypeNodeHelper (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35286:57)
>       at addPropertyToElementList (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35680:59)
>       at createTypeNodesFromResolvedType (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35630:25)
>       at createTypeNodeFromObjectType (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35460:35)
>       at createAnonymousTypeNode (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35412:42)
>       at typeToTypeNodeHelper (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35320:28)
>       at C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35114:106
>       at withContext (C:\Users\user1\Development\Proj\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:35155:37)

`webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const cmd = require('commander')
const outputdir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
const flat = require('flat')
const {BundleAnalyzerPlugin} = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ssr = require('./websrc/ssrRegistered.js')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const WorkerPlugin = require('worker-plugin')
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin')
var HardSourceWebpackPlugin = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin')

const getEnvVars = () => {
  const vars = flat({process: {env: process.env}})
  Object.keys(vars).forEach(key => (vars[key] = JSON.stringify(vars[key])))

  return vars
}

const htmlMinifyOpts = {
  collapseWhitespace: true,
  collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
  minifyCSS: true,
  removeComments: true,
  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
  removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
  useShortDoctype: true
}
cmd
  .option('--mode [mode]', '', process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
  .option('--report')
  .option('--debug')
  .option('--page [page]', '', '') // page for dev server to open
  .parse(process.argv)
const mode = cmd.mode

const opts = {
  entry: {app: './websrc/app.tsx'},
  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    path: outputdir,
    publicPath: '/',
    // show relative paths in sourcemaps
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]',
    devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]',
    pathinfo: false
  },
  mode,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          cacheCompression: false
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          experimentalWatchApi: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: outputdir,
    open: true,
    openPage: path.normalize(cmd.page),
    overlay: {
      errors: true
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
    // host: '0.0.0.0'
  },
  devtool: mode === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'proj1',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'websrc/index.tsx',
      inject: false,
      ssr: ssr({outputdir})(),
      mode,
      minify: mode === 'production' ? htmlMinifyOpts : {}
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(getEnvVars()),
    new CopyPlugin(['websrc/static']),
    new WorkerPlugin({globalObject: 'self'}),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
    new HardSourceWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules']
  }
}

if (cmd.report) {
  opts.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerMode: 'static'}))
}

if (cmd.debug) console.log(opts) // eslint-disable-line no-console

module.exports = opts
```

Comment: Please post your code where you init `unescapeLeadingUnderscores` or use `unescapeLeadingUnderscores.length`

Comment: @zerocewl That's not my code, this is typescript's code...

Comment: ah sry, try to remove node_modules folder and reinstall, what did you changed last?

Comment: @zerocewl I tried, same thing:( I can't point to one change I recently made..

Comment: hm try to use some older versions via npm install...

Comment: can you post your tsconfig file?

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: @CarlosCrespo Please see edited question.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Please see edited question.

Comment: @user3378165 interesting,  are you using `create-react-app`? The issue might lie in the typescript loader that is being used.  perhaps you can add your `package.json`

Comment: @AluanHaddad no, I didn't use `create-react-app`, I added `package.json` to the question.

Comment: Your webconfig.config might also be useful here

Comment: @CarlosCrespo do you mean my `webpack.config`?

Comment: yeah! sorry :/! I meant webpack.config

Comment: Would it possible that you create a minimal Github/GitLab/Bitbucket Repository so we can reproduce the issue? Only the minimal configuration that triggers this error. From the files alone it is nearly impossible to help you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it appears that you may have ran into a bug that is listed in the issues section on the Typescript GitHub.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21801

After reviewing this, my suggestion would be to do some null checking throughout your application. My best guess would be you are running into some race conditions on the initialization of the application/or component. Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: @user3378165 do you have maybe some **dynamic function names** in your application? That can cause this type of error. See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33604 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78658